# `fout.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e), sizeof(e) );` why here casting into `const char*`?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, file-handling, reinterpret-cast

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct emp
        {
            char name[20];
            int age;
        };

int main()
{
    emp e1={"Abhishek", 22},e2;
    
    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("vicky.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e1),24);
    fout.close();

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("vicky.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e2),24);
    fin.close();

    std::cout<<e2.name<<" "<<e2.age<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Why it is necessary to do `reinterpret_cast` with 1st argument of `write` and `read` function ?

why we casting address of type `emp` particularly to `const char*` and `char*`  in `write` and `read` function respectively ?

Comment: Because that is what the function requires.

Comment: Because `write`/`read` take respectively  `const char*`/`char*` as argument and you are telling compiler "I know `emp*` is not `char*`, but I want you to treat it like `char*`, I don't care about consequences".

Comment: @Yksisarvinen got it.

Comment: `char` is a misnomer in C++. A better name would be `byte`: these two functions (like all low-level IO functions) operate on *byte buffers*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph what is meant by *byte buffers* exactly ?

Comment: @KonradRudolph except that `char` is not required to be 8-bits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph sorry I am not getting can you tell in little bit brief please ?

Comment: The data in memory (and in your binary file) representing an emp is made out of bytes. A sequence of bytes of a certain size is called a byte buffer. So anything a char* points to is a sequence of bytes. To be able to write an emp structure to the file, the write operation want a char* but you have an emp* and they are not the same thing. An emp is (hopefully) represented by 24 bytes in memory (you might want to check sizeof(emp)==24). And you basically have to say to write, use the address of emp as first the adress of your first byte (a char), which you do by static_casting.

Comment: @RichardCritten Neither is a byte (byte ≠ octet!). In C and C++, `char` = byte, by definition. Both in size and in (aliasing and addressing) behaviour.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Sorry, the explanation goes *way* beyond the scope of a comment. You’ll need to [find a book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/1968/) that explains the fundamentals of memory in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why it is necessary to do `reinterpret_cast` with 1st argument of `write` and `read` function ?

Because the first argument to `write()` is a `const char*` and the first argument to `read()` is a `char*`.

> why we casting address of type `emp` particularly to `const char*` and `char*`  in `write` and `read` function respectively ?

You can cast both to `char*` in your case - but, in the case of `write`, which doesn't need a mutable object since it's not going to modify it in any way, you would not be able to `write` a `const` object if you try to cast to `char*`.

Works:

```
const emp e1 = {"Abhishek", 22};
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e1), sizeof e1);

emp e2 = {"Foo", 23};
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e2), sizeof e2);
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e2), sizeof e2);
```

Doesn't even compile:

```
const emp e1 = {"Abhishek", 22};
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e1), sizeof e1);
```

---

Unrelated to the question but worth a note:
You have hardcoded the size of `emp` to `24`. Don't. Use `sizeof` to get the actual size. Even if an `int` is 4 bytes on your current platform, it may not be if you compile it on a different platform.

Related to the above: Use fixed width types (like `uint32_t` for a 4 byte unsigned integer) if you want the file format to work on different platforms and take care of [*endianness*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Object_representation) - but still use `sizeof`, since counting the sizes manually when you add/remove members is prone to lead to mistakes.

Comment: `fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e2), sizeof e2);` how it works ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane A `char*` can be implicitly converted to a `const char*` (from non-`const` to `const` is considered safe) and `sizeof e2` gives the size of `e2` in bytes.

Comment: got it. and one thing `sizeof e2` it should be `sizeof(e2)` isn't it ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane  Great! ... and no, the [`sizeof` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) has two forms. `sizeof(type)` and `sizeof expression`. Well, `sizeof (expression)` would work too but it'd still use the expression form.

Comment: @AbhishekMane You have `e1` and `e2` in your program. `sizeof e1` and `sizeof e2` should work if your compiler is ok.

Comment: @AbhishekMane You are using a _type_ (the first `sizeof` form). What I showed in my answer was the _expression_ form, like this:        https://ideone.com/WNoHIp

Comment: Now got it. Thanks